# CSS padding not working properly?

Tags: css

I think i have a issue with the padding.
I made a simple box with only just a `padding: 20px;` and for me it looks like the padding-bottom is more than 20px.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Here is my simple css:

```
.panel {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-default {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #fff;
}

.panel-default > .panel-body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid_4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I use 960 Grid System, but i dont think this happend because of this.
And i have in my `html, body {}` the box-sizing set up to border-box and the line-height to 24px.

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: panel-body must be having a line-height/margin/padding of its own.

Comment: m not able to see any change.Padding is same at top and bottom. see here http://jsfiddle.net/vryLz62n/

Comment: wait a min..you are talking about the white background or gap out side of white background box?

Comment: Not sure try to add `padding:0; margin:0` for `panel-body` class

Comment: you don't actually have padding 20 px , you should put it in class panel-body.

Comment: @Leothelion on the fiddle ist working fine, but look at my screenshot. I have here another screenshot:https://picr.ws/images/674ab5b25d15437c33dc78f80124615f.png and that padding definitely looks wrong to me.

**EDIT**: im talking about the text inside the box.

Comment: may be it is because of the other elements as it available in your img

Comment: @FrancisSaul that doesn't make any difference

Comment: @Rarely in your screenshot where you post [] then its out side of box but inside box padding is same.

Comment: @Leothelion i dont want padding outside. i want that the text is centered in the middle wit a padding of 20px; the width and height of the `.panel` is set to auto so it should automaticlly ajust to the padding.

Comment: @Rarely, padding is 20px but text is taking 2 px but on top and bottom too so its same. Not getting your issue ...sorry

Comment: Do you use AdminLTE ? I have got the same problem with panels and I don't remember how I fixed it. Can we go to your website ?

Comment: @SatanicGeek No, dont use that. And at the moment i dont have any website just doing it on localhost.

Comment: Did you tried to see the padding, margin, etc ... of your div with the developer console of your browser ?

Comment: @SatanicGeek yes, no difference, but its telling me its a padding of 20px;

Comment: So it's a padding of 20px I think. If you want to reduce the padding, try 17px or 16px.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is alright, the problem is with your `margin-bottom: 20px;`.

This should be your .css:

```
.panel {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: relative;
}

.panel-default {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  background: #fff;
}

.panel-default > .panel-body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

This code will have the effect you are looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/r67nxyL5/

Comment: I need the margin-bottom because when i have 2 boxes in needs a bit of space between.

Comment: Have you tried to give the following div a `margin-top`? Might already fix your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have a margin somewhere.You can check this by inspecting the element using your internet browser (right click).

or you can try floating your .panel-default and giving it a display block like so:

```
.panel-default {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

if this doesn't work it's definitely a margin-bottom somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you didn't remove the default margin from the paragraph tag, which adds up to the bottom.

Try to set up paragraph margins to 0.